# How can I replace a character with a newline in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, replace

I am trying to replace a character - say `;` - with a new line using `replace-string` and/or `replace-regexp` in Emacs.

I have tried the following commands:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-string` <kbd>RET</kbd> `;` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\n`

  This will replace `;` with two characters: `\n`.
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regex` <kbd>RET</kbd> `;` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\n`

  This results in the following error (shown in the minibuffer):

  > Invalid use of `' in replacement text.

What's wrong with using `replace-string` for this task? Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 523, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-string` <kbd>RET</kbd> `;` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>.

- <kbd>C-q</kbd> for `quoted-insert`,
- <kbd>C-j</kbd> is a newline.

Comment: C-q is really `quote-insert` which quotes the next character.

Comment: I believe it's actually "quoted" rather than "quote", as in "quoted-insert". At least that's the way it is on version 22.1.

Comment: `C-j` is a literal `0x0a` control code, versus `Ret` which is the key next to your quote and sends `0x0d`.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes

Comment: Note for vim users, using `C-j` in **emacs**, while `C-m` in **vim**.

Comment: @JonathanArkell That's a description *how* it works, but not *why*. Within the editor, Ret produces 0x0a, so why should it produce 0x0d in quoted-insert? That doesn't make any sense.  (Just because the internal keyboard code is 0x0d for historical reasons? We use key maps all over the place, why not here where it makes perfect sense?)

Comment: Above works in emacs but not in spacemacs. How can it be done in spacemacs using emacs mode?

Answer (score 96):

There are four ways I've found to put a newline into the minibuffer.

1. <kbd>C-o</kbd>
2. <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>
3. <kbd>C-q</kbd> `12` (12 is the octal value of newline)
4. <kbd>C-x o</kbd> to the main window, kill a newline with <kbd>C-k</kbd>, then <kbd>C-x o</kbd> back to the minibuffer, yank it with <kbd>C-y</kbd>

Comment: +1 for mentioning `C-o`! One less key stroke compared to `C-q C-j`. Hadn't thought of using that one before.

Comment: Thanks for version 4! Helpful if you have C-o and C-q rebound.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain why C-o works and C-q C-j doesn't?

Comment: `C-o` doesn't move the point after inserting the newline in the minibuffer, so you still need to press the right arrow key as well if you want to insert something after the newline in the replacement string.

Comment: On my version of Emacs 25.2.2, `C-o` will enter a newline in the main window when using search, while `C-q C-j` will enter the newline in the minibuffer. `C-o` does work with query - replace though.

Answer (score 30):

Don't forget that you can always cut and paste into the minibuffer.

So you can just copy a newline character (or any string) from your buffer, then yank it when prompted for the replacement text.

Comment: It's really a good idea for the characters which I don't know the key bind.

Comment: Ahah ! so simple !

Comment: This could need some expansion for the uninitiated. E.g. how can those actions actually be achieved (actual concrete steps)? As the OP has left the building, it could be a prime example of editing beyond copy editing.

Answer (score 11):

More explicitly:

To replace the semicolon character (;) with a newline, follow these exact steps.

1. locate the cursor at the upper left of buffer the containing text you want to change
2. Type `m-x` replace-string and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>
3. The mini-buffer will display something like this:
   Replace string (default ^  -> ):
4. Type in the character you want to replace. In this case, `;`
   and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>
5. The mini-buffer will display something like this:

   string ; with:
6. Now execute `C-q C-j`
7. All instances of semicolon will be replaced a newline (from the cursor location to the end of the buffer will now appear)

There is a bit more to it than the original explanation says.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to text mode:

```
M-x text-mode
```

Highlight the block to indent.

Indent: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> </kbd>

Switch back to whatever mode...

Answer (score -2):

Inline just:

`C-M-S-%` (if the binding keys are still the default) and then
`replace-string` <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: What is meant by "inline"? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58334096/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).