# How to replace space character with line break(LF) in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to use "replace-string" command to achieve this function,
but how to type in "LF" character?
it's confuse me so much...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace a character with a newline in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613022/how-to-replace-a-character-with-a-newline-in-emacs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `C-q C-j` to search/replace a newline

Comment: I know this answer is old, but `C-h C-j` is undefined for me.  What is the name of the function associated with this sequence?

Comment: @LoremIpsum `C-q` is for a quoted insert. Whatever you type next (`C-j` for instance) is literally inserted rather than being interpreted. So while in the 'replace' minibuffer prompt, `C-q C-j` puts a literal `^J` character in your input to it rather than interpreting it like pressing enter normally.