# When exporting to text in org-mode: Insert blank lines between headings

Tags: emacs, org-mode

As I often collect lists of open question in org-mode, I want to be able to easily export the subtree to text with some space between the single headings (such that there is some space for note-taking on a printed copy).

Org-structure looks like this:

```
* topic xyz
** question 1
** question 2
** question 3
```

Expected layout of the text export containing configurable number of blank lines between (or after) headings:

```
━━━━━━━━━━
topic xyz
━━━━━━━━━━

question 1
══════════





question 2
══════════





question 3
══════════
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute a regex replacement in the exported text file:

`replace-regex` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^[═]+$` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\&` <kbd>C-o</kbd> <kbd>C-o</kbd> <kbd>C-o</kbd>

<kbd>C-o</kbd> inserts the newlines. c.p. [How to replace a character with a newline in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613022/how-to-replace-a-character-with-a-newline-in-emacs)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to add newlines to your export without formatting your org file. You can enforce newlines by using `\\` on each line where you want an empty line to appear.

In your case:

```
* topic xyz
** Question 1
\\
\\
\\
** Question 2...
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The backslashes are exported too. As I do not want to modify my org-file, this would not to be the ideal solution anyway.