# How to replace a character with a newline in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I tried to follow this to replace a character with newline in Spacemacs but that key combination replaced it with a space instead of newline.

[How to replace a character with a newline in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613022/how-to-replace-a-character-with-a-newline-in-emacs)

How can this be accomplished in Spacemacs?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to work exactly the same with Spacemacs (`C-q` `C-j` will replace with a newline).

You can check if your keys are correctly mapped with the describe-key command (`C-h k`):

- `C-q` runs the command quoted-insert
  and
- `C-j` runs the command electric-newline-and-maybe-indent (result with my Spacemacs)