# convert \n (end-of-line) instruction to actual end of line

Tags: linux, emacs, newline

I have a file exported from a mysql database which include `\n` (literally) for end-of-line. This file is composed of one line only because the end-of-line symbol is not interpreted

> my file is like this \n there is another line \n and I would like "\n" to be interpreted

How can I replace `\n`with a actual new line?

There are a lot of answer to this question with notepad++ but I am on Linux. I tried [this solution with emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613022/how-can-i-replace-a-character-with-a-newline-in-emacs) but `C-q C-j` did not create a new line in my buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(replace-string "\\n" "\n")
```

If you are looking for an interactive keyboard sequence, try M-% <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> C-j <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>
(but realize that Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions).

If you are on some godforsaken platform where C-j doesn't emit a newline, try C-q C-j or the octal sequence C-q <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> (recall that LF is octal 012).

Comment: Actually, the question you linked to already covers all these bases. I'm guessing you missed the answer which reveals how to input an octal character code.